# fsutil can't create more than 4 hard links to a file in win srv 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, hardlink, fsutil

I got an error message when I created 5th hard link to a file using `fsutil`:

> Error:  An attempt was made to create more links on a file than the file system
>   supports.

I was quite surprised because impression is that NTFS can support up to 1023 hard links to a single file. Can anyone shed some light on this issue? It looks like it is the limitation of `fsutil` instead of that of  Windows Server 2003. Thanks.

Comment: Was this a clean install of Windows 2003, or did it get upgraded from 2000?

Comment: I believe it is a clean install. The hard drive has been reformatted as NTFS just recently.

Comment: I know this was an issue on NT and 2000, which is why I asked. Are there any policies you know of? Is it native storage or SAN?

Comment: I also downloaded GnuWin32 and managed to create more than 4 links using ln command.

Comment: It is not a native storage server. We did create disk array using some HP utility. Anyway, I will use ln command to create hardlinks. I really don't see it is a limitation of the file system itself.